# gradle build test fails regarding database connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle, azure-devops

i try to build my Spring Boot Project with Gradle and Docker within an Azure Pipeline.

My Problem is that during gradle build process there is always one failing test with an jdbc Exception that it can't create a bean.

1. Why is there a test connecting to the Database? I
   have mocked all my repositories regarding Unit tests.
2. can i somehow disable that? I only want my Unit tests to run during
   the build process.
3. It should be able to connect anyway, locally everything works fine and i
   set up a Service Connection inside Azure Devops to the Resource
   Group where the Database resides. Am i missing something?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It's recommended to share the error log snippet, gradle build configuration, and devops pipeline definition in the statement, it's hard to help based on the current info.